# How to export the Network Diagram View to an image in Microsoft Project 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, visualization

Is there a way to export the Network Diagram View in Microsoft Project 2010 to an image format including *all* the image contents, not just what's rendered in the screen? I've tried the Task, Copy, Copy Picture but only copy what fits in the screen, very disappointing.

I'm also interested in learning if it's possible to export to another format. The PDF export breaks in several pages, such as the Gantt diagram, for example.

Comment: Dang... I thought there was a "Save as Image" option - it exists in other Office 2010 programs - but they don't have it. Seems like a oversight on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Have you tried to print to a PDF/XPS (documents that have more export options) or to capture the screen (with the diagram as a whole or in pieces if it doesn't fit in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Print as pdf file you can see the full network diagram.**

Step 1: Download and install **primopdf** free pdf convertor tool
http://www.primopdf.com/

Step 2: Open the network diagram in **MS project 
View->Network Diagram**

Step 3: Right click on the menu bar and click **Project Guide**
(If project guide already available in tool bar ignore this step)

Step 4: Click the "**Report**" in the Project Guide Tool bar
Click "Print Current view as a report"

Step 5: Select Radio Button "**One Page**" or "**Multiple Pages**"
Click Print (If you need to preview, Click Print Preview to see the preview)

Step 6: Select **primopdf** as Name of the printer in the Print dialogue and click ok.

Step 7: In the pdf reader, you can + or - icon to **view the Network diagram in single view and one page itself**.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions of printing to PDF result in a different appearance of the chart, and loss of some color information you may have put into the network map.  The only way I have found to preserve those color and line thickness and etc aspects which are shown on the edit screen, is to screen capture portions of the diagram and then re-assemble them as graphic regions on another format such as a spreadsheet.

Using the Windows snipping tool (screen capture tool), you could for example capture a diagram which takes up 4x your physical screen available:
1. scroll to upper left of your diagram.  Snip the screen contents and paste into an Excel sheet.
2. scroll to upper right of your diagram.  Snip the screen contents, paste into the Excel sheet to the right of snip #1.
3. bottom left, snip, paste.
4. bottom right, snip, paste.

That seems to be as good as it gets until MS would develop a print layout option that would exactly match the on screen editing view.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes Project's network diagrams are not very user-friendly. I've found it much more helpful to create my own (e.g. in Project). Although this can be laborious, it has the distinct advantage of forcing you to go through your schedule line-by-line and identify all the inter-relationships between tasks. I can't tell you how many errors I've found  (i.e. wrong/illogical/missing successors/predecessors) in complex Gantt charts that have slipped past any number of reviewers just by creating network diagrams manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. install adobe scansoft
2. print to pdf
3. print your job with adobe scansoft printer: set the paper to "customize", set big size,
   set to landscape or portrait, set to fit printer
4. click OK
5. print preview
6. print

You will see your job in one sheet.